# Drawing a "photodiode" symbol with TiKz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

A photodiode is typically depicted in the literature as a circle partially "hidden" by a rectangular bar. How does one go about drawing it with TiKz?

[image: photodiode symbol]

[image]

So far, I am using `clip` to "hide" part of a circle. Then, I superimpose a rectangle. The problem with this approach is that it simply masks the output (i.e., the resulting PDF still describes a full circle).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (10mm,10mm);
\draw[inner color=orange!20, outer color=orange, draw, very thick]  (2.5mm,5mm) circle (4mm);
\draw[fill] (0,0) rectangle (1.2mm,10mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show what you tried yourself. Can you for example draw a normal circle in TikZ?

Comment: This is not photodiode symbol For it see `circuitikz`, manual  ,pp 239:-)

Comment: @Zarko Thanks! I am aware of how a photodiode is represented in an electrical circuit diagram. In laser optics, however, photodiodes are typically represented with the symbol I shared.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I will do as soon as I get close... so far I am trying to use `circle` and `rectangle`, but I am not able to "cut" the circle such that part of it is hidden (i.e., to avoid relying on just placing the rectangle on top of the circle).

Comment: @Zarko I have added another image to illustrate further what I mean :-)

Comment: @MikeD. Clipping away the top part is easy. Please show your circle and rectangle code

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz please take a look at the edited question.

Comment: @MikeD. Thanks for updating your question! What's the problem with "... it simply masks the output"?

Comment: If you don't want this, you could use an `arc` instead of a `circle`, but clipping is much easier.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I guess it's my OCD... Thanks for the tip on using `arc`! By the way, is it possible to shift the position of the center of the radial gradient inside the circle?

Comment: @MikeD. Have you tried a ball shade?

Comment: `\draw[ball color=orange, shading angle=-45, draw, very thick]  (2.5mm,5mm) circle (4mm);`

Comment: ... and see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268411/36296 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58635/36296 on how to create your own shadings

Comment: If you are going to worry about the structure underlying the visual appearance in the PDF, you have a lot of worrying to do and clipped circles will be the least of your worries. Ti*k*Z does this all over the place. Every time you use an arrow tip or `double`, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make use of a `\pic`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/photo diode/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{photo diode/.cd, #1}
            \path[photo diode/bulb]
                ({-sqrt(3)*0.225},0) 
                arc[start angle=210, end angle=-30, radius=0.45]
                -- cycle;
            \path[photo diode/base] (-0.5,0) -- (0.5,0);
            \coordinate (-north) at (0,0.675);
            \coordinate (-south) at (0,0);
        }
    },
    photo diode/base/.style={
        draw,
        line width=4pt
    },
    photo diode/bulb/.style={
        draw,
        ball color=orange
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic (P) at (0,0) {photo diode};

\pic[red] (Q) at (2,0) {photo diode={
    bulb/.append style={ball color=green}
}};

\draw (P-south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (Q-south);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Edit to exactly position the anchor coordinates (thanks to Sebastiano):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/photo diode/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{photo diode/.cd, #1}
            \path[photo diode/bulb]
                ({-sqrt(3)*0.225},0) 
                arc[start angle=210, end angle=-30, radius=0.45]
                coordinate[midway, yshift={0.5*\pgflinewidth}] (-north);
            \path[photo diode/base] (-0.5,0) -- (0.5,0)
                coordinate[midway, yshift={-0.5*\pgflinewidth}] (-south);
        }
    },
    photo diode/base/.style={
        draw,
        line width=4pt
    },
    photo diode/bulb/.style={
        draw,
        ball color=orange
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic (P) at (0,0) {photo diode};

\pic[red] (Q) at (2,0) {photo diode={
    bulb/.append style={ball color=green}
}};

\draw (P-south) -- ++(0,-0.5) -| (Q-south);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would put the wire under the red rectangle.

Comment: @Sebastiano I also saw this the very moment I posted it =D . You are totally right, it looks strange.